# Having a ton of trouble with a simple div layout in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm pretty new to using div layouts in CSS and having a really hard time getting what I want. What I'm trying to do is have the "RESUME" and "PORTFOLIO" boxes (which will be buttons later) underneath the picture and bio, perfectly lined up with their edges. So basically it would be like this:

[PICTURE] [BIO] (both same height, on the same line)

[RESUME] [PORTFOLIO] (flatter, both same height, on the same line)

(left/right edges of all four boxes line up with the one above/below)

What I have so far is kiiinda like that, but the boxes that are supposed to be at the bottom are at the top. And the edges keep getting cut off. And they don't line up. And when I shrink the browser window things get really wild.

Anyway, if someone could please help me untangle this and get what I want, that'd be great!

(Note: For some reason the sizes of the divs are a little messed up in the snippet below, but it's the shapes and positions I'm concerned with anyway)

```css
.about {
  width: 55%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding-bottom: 600px;
}
.Jordan {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
}
.JordanInner,
.bioInner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.JordanInner img,
.bioInner p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: RobotoThin;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000000;
}
.bio {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.resume,
.port {
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">

  <div class="Jordan">
    <div class="JordanInner">
      <img src="http://orig06.deviantart.net/96b7/f/2014/133/a/2/blobfish_mermaid_by_guavajagular-d7i721c.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="resume">RESUME</div>
  </div>


  <div class="bio">
    <div class="bioInner">
      <p>
        <span style="font-family: MinionPro; font-size: 18px; letter-spacing: 2px;"> ABOUT JORDAN</span>
        <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
        dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
        laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque
        sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis
        leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="port">PORTFOLIO</div>





  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For neat layouts I started using `flex` styles of CSS3. Life is so much simpler! :)  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Have you tried using a framework, such as bootstrap?

Comment: Here's a fiddle of a "dirty" solution of what you want https://jsfiddle.net/enmsaqmv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is kinda tricky and I'm not really sure of what you want to do... but maybe this CSS can give you a hint to start designing your layout.

```css
.about {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
.about:after {
  content:" ";
  display:block;
  clear: both;
}
.Jordan,
.bio {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
.JordanInner,
.bioInner {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.resume,
.port {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">

  <div class="Jordan">
    <div class="JordanInner">
      <img src="http://orig06.deviantart.net/96b7/f/2014/133/a/2/blobfish_mermaid_by_guavajagular-d7i721c.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="resume">RESUME</div>
  </div>


  <div class="bio">
    <div class="bioInner">
      <p>
        <span style="font-family: MinionPro; font-size: 18px; letter-spacing: 2px;"> ABOUT JORDAN</span>
        <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
        dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
        laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque
        sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis
        leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="port">PORTFOLIO</div>





  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely a massive step in the right direction. Thanks so much!